# Probabilistic Algorithm for Determining if a Matrix is Nonsingular.

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, determinant

I was reading through *Problem-Solving Through Problems* and ran into the following problem,

> Determine whether the following matrix is singular or nonsingular:
>   $$ \begin{bmatrix} 54401 & 5768 & 15982 & 103790 \\
> 33223 & 26563 & 23165 & 71489 \\
> 36799 & 37189 & 16596 & 46152 \\
> 21689 & 55538 & 79922 & 51237 \end{bmatrix}. $$
>   (Hint: A matrix $A$ is nonsingular if $\det{A} \neq 0$. Examine the parity of the determinant of the given matrix; that is, compute the determinant modulo $2$.)
>
> *Larson. Problem-Solving Through Problems.* New York: Springer-Verlag, 1983. Page 98.

This was in the section on modular arithmetic. I suspect that the author is looking for an answer using the cofactor formula and dropping any even terms. Is this correct, and if so,

**Does this lead to an efficient probabilistic algorithm to determine if a matrix is invertible?** How would such an algorithm compare to standard techniques taught in an introductory linear algebra course, such as using Gauss-Jordan, big formula, cofactors, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reduce each entry of the matrix modulo $2$, you end up with the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$. This matrix is clearly invertible since the columns are easily verified to be linearly independent (just through visual inspection for example). All this tells you that the determinant is congruent to $1$ modulo $2$, i.e. it is odd. In particular, this means that the determinant is non-zero.

I'm not too sure what you mean by a "probabilistic algorithm". In the end, we still need a method to evaluate whether the reduced determinant is non-zero and this likely means that we'll have to resort to one of our standard algorithms. The entries of the matrix may be reduced, but I am doubtful that the overall run-time will be lowered.